# android drawBitmap How to make it not clear before

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to do a fingers according to coordinate and drawing pictures, but every time the content of the drawing will be cleared before.Can you tell me what to do?

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mMoveX, mMoveY, mPaint);

Comment: `"I want to do a fingers"` what do you want to do?

Comment: According to the fingers to move, and then draw the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(mDrawBitmap);